# How to disable parallelExecution for fastOptJS/fullOptJS?

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I have an SBT project with different scalajs sub projects (and other jvm subproject) and when I run "fullOptJS" SBT is trying to compile all js projects in parallel.

Since fullOptJS is quite CPU and memory intensive it ends with an OutOfMemoryException,

I tried to set parallelExecution to false both in each project settings and in the parent js aggregate project in my project/build.scala file but SBT still start all sub project optimization in parallel.

Something like that:

```
parallelExecution in fullOptJS := false,
parallelExecution in fullOptJS in Compile := false
```

Is it not the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

`fullOptJS` does not honor `parallelExecution`, but it honors `scalaJSLinkerConfig`. You can set it with:

```
scalaJSLinkerConfig in (Compile, fullOptJS) ~= { _.withParallel(false) }
```

Note that this only affects the Scala.js optimizer. It does not have any impact on the additional pass with the Google Closure Compiler. I don't know whether that one does anything in parallel or not.